# uploading 4 files at a time in a single database insert query

Tags: php, mysql, database, file

i want to upload 4 file at a time in a single insert database query how to to that? below is my code

```
$name_array     = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
$type_array     = $_FILES['files']['type'];
$size_array     = $_FILES['files']['size'];

for ($i=0; $i<count($tmp_name_array); $i++  ){

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],"uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
        $query  = "INSERT INTO photos (`file_name`, `file_name1`,`file_name2`,`file_name3` `file_type`,`size`,`caption`)  VALUES('$name_array[$i]',$name_array[$i]',$name_array[$i]',$name_array[$i]','$ty   pe_array[$i]','$size_array[$i]','$caption[$i]') ";
        mysql_query($query);
        var_dump($query);
        echo "The file $name_array[$i] has been upload ";
    } else {
        echo "The file $name_array[$i] has not been upload ";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use deprecated **mysql_** functions. Change them to **mysqli_** or **PDO**.

Now to insert multiple entries to database using single query, you can use this syntax:

```
INSER INTO table_name (columnName1, columnName2, ...) VALUES
(val1_1, val1_2, ...),
(val2_1, val2_2, ...),
...
```

So with your code you can do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO photos (`file_name`, `file_name1`,`file_name2`,`file_name3` `file_type`,`size`,`caption`)  VALUES ";
$inserts = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) {

  if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])) {
    $inserts[] = "('{$name_array[$i]}', '{$name_array[$i]}', '{$name_array[$i]}', '{$name_array[$i]}', '{$type_array[$i]}', '{$size_array[$i]}', '{$caption[$i]}')";
  }
}

if (!empty($inserts)) {
    mysql_query($query.implode(", ", $inserts));
} else {
    echo "No files to be uploaded and saved";
}
```

But still, change this to prepared statement (it will eliminate missing `'` before parameters).

Comment: @CyedSafir Check PHP version. Older PHP versions do not support shorthand array `[]`, replace it with `array()`  (`$inserts = [];`)

Comment: my php version is 5.3.5

Comment: @CyedSafir so use non-shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 2):

from your code above i think you are trying to do something like this. here is a little piece of code to upload multiple files.

```
$file_arr= array();

    for($i=0,$j=0; $i<count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++)
    {
       if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i] != "")
    {
        $file_arr[$j] = array();
        $file_arr[$j]['name']       = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $file_arr[$j]['size']   = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $file_arr[$j]['type']       = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $file_arr[$j]['tmp_name']   = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $j++;
    }
}
if(count($file_arr) > 0){
    $file_location = 'uploads/files/';

    for($i=0; $i<count($file_arr); $i++)
    {   

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_arr[$i]['tmp_name'],$file_location.$file_arr[$i]['name'])){
            $msg = "uploaded successfully";

            $query="INSERT INTO photos (`file_name`, `file_type`,`size`,`caption`)  VALUES('$file_arr['name']','$file_arr['type']','$file_arr['size']','$caption') ";


            $q2 =mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

            }
        }
    }
```